# why simditor-mention doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I import simditor in `.vue` files . it work well . but when I import simditor-mention,it doesn't work at all. please tell me how to get it work.Thanks.

This is my code.

```
import simditor from 'simditor'
import 'simditor-mention'
```

> https://github.com/mycolorway/simditor
>
> https://github.com/mycolorway/simditor-mention

Comment: shouldn't it be like `import someVarName from 'simditor-mention'`

Comment: I already tried,it doesn't work also

Answer (score 0):

1. The source code of [simditor-mention](https://github.com/mycolorway/simditor-mention/blob/master/lib/simditor-mention.js) is in the lib folder.
2. It doesn't have an `exports default` <s>nor `module.exports`</s>
3. The [demo.html](https://github.com/mycolorway/simditor-mention/blob/master/demo.html) uses the lib from the script tags as `<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/simditor-mention.js"></script>`

So, you can't use the `import` syntax as you are trying above.

**you should try:**

```
require('simditor-mention/lib/simditor-mention.js')
```

in your main js file if you want it accessible throughout your vuejs application, or else the desired `.vue` file.

**or**

you can import the script tag in your html, like so: `<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/simditor-mention.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, and I have some questions.

1.It have an module.exports in lib/simditor-mention.js

2.I try require('simditor-mention/lib/simditor-mention.js') and import 'simditor-mention/lib/simditor-mention.js',it doesn't work also

Comment: To use `import` the library must have `exports default` or `export const someVar`. `module.exports` means you need to use `require(somePath)` format in a node/node-like environment. Did you add `declare let SimditorMention` also, what about the html script tag way?

Comment: My application use ```.vue```files . so  html script tag doesn't work. and add ```declare let SimditorMention``` doesn't work also.

Comment: Are you rendering server side? @smallStone

Comment: Thank you very much